# simple parallel download using a connection Pool class using cpprestsdk

Tags: c++

The following is a simple class for establishing multiple http connections, mainly for downloading a list of small files:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

    class ConnectionPool
{
public:
    ConnectionPool(size_t nWorkers, std::wstring baseUri) :BaseUri(baseUri)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nWorkers; i++) Pool.emplace_back(http_client(baseUri), http_request(methods::GET));
    }

    void ResetState(size_t nWorkers, std::wstring baseUri)
    {
        BaseUri = baseUri;
        nDone = 0;
        Pool.clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nWorkers; i++) Pool.emplace_back(http_client(baseUri), http_request(methods::GET));
    }

    void ResizePool(size_t nWorkers)
    {
        Pool.resize(nWorkers, { http_client(BaseUri) , http_request(methods::GET) });
    }

    /*template<typename Function>
    void DownloadAsync(std::vector<std::wstring> Uris, const Function& f)//Not implemented
    {
        WorkItems = Uris;
        const size_t limit = (std::min)(Pool.size(), WorkItems.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; i++) assignWork(i, f);
    }*/

    template<typename Function>
    void DownloadSync(const std::vector<std::wstring> Uris, const Function& f)
    {
        std::wcout << "*DownloadSync Started*" << std::endl;
        WorkItems = Uris;
         for (size_t i = nDone = 0, limit = nActive = std::min(Pool.size(), WorkItems.size()); i < limit; ++i) assignWork(i, f);

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m1);
        cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return nActive == 0; });
        std::wcout << "*DownloadSync Ended*" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename Function>
    void assignWork(int pidx, const Function& f)
    {
        //m2 isn't needed, right?!
        //m2.lock();
        if (nDone >= WorkItems.size())
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m1);
            --nActive;
            cv.notify_one();
            //m2.unlock();
            return;
        }
        const auto wItem = WorkItems[nDone];
        int cIdx = nDone;
        ++nDone;
        //m2.unlock();

        std::wcout << L"Worker " << pidx << L": Assigning/t" << wItem << L" succeed" << std::endl;
        auto& [client, request] = Pool[pidx];

        request.set_request_uri(wItem);
        client.request(request).then([=](pplx::task <http_response>  responseTask) {
            try {
                if (auto response = responseTask.get(); response.status_code() == http::status_codes::OK)
                {
                    f(response, cIdx);
                    std::wcout << L"Worker " << pidx << L": Downloading/t" << wItem <<L" succeed"<< std::endl;
                }
                else std::wcout << L"Worker " << pidx << L": Downloaded/t" << wItem << L" failed with the following code "<< response.status_code() << std::endl;
            }
            catch (const web::http::http_exception& ex) { std::wcout << L"Worker " << pidx<<L":Requesting "<<wItem << L" failed with exception (" << ex.error_code()<<L"): "  << ex.what() << " : "  << std::endl; }

            try { assignWork(pidx, f);}
            catch (const std::exception& ex) { std::wcout << L"Worker " << pidx << L": Assigning/t" << wItem << L" Failed with exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl; } });
    }

    ~ConnectionPool()
    {
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::pair<http_client, http_request>> Pool;
    std::vector<std::wstring> WorkItems;
    std::wstring BaseUri;
    std::mutex m1/*,m2*/;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<int> nActive = 0, nDone = 0;
};

int main()
{
//....code....//
ConnectionPool con(n, L"base url");
        con.DownloadSync(urls, [](http_response res, int idx)
            {
                auto outFile = fstream::open_ostream(std::to_wstring(idx) + L".ext").get();
                res.body().read_to_end(outFile.streambuf()).wait();
                outFile.close().wait();
            });
}
```

Comment: Any specific aspect to review?

Answer (score 1):

## Interface

Prefer [`wstring_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) to `wstring` for parameters to save one copy:

```
ConnectionPool(std::size_t nWorkers, std::wstring_view baseUri)
```

(Whether this is effective depends on the way `http_client` works.)

> ```
> void assignWork(int pidx, const Function& f)
> ```

`std::size_t pidx`, I guess?  (Same for other occurrences of `int`.)

> ```
> ~ConnectionPool()
> {
> }
> ```

Remove this destructor; the only thing it does is prevent move operations from generating.

## Locking

> ```
> //m2 isn't needed, right?!
> //m2.lock();
> ```

Regardless of whether it's needed, use

```
std::lock_guard lock{m2};
```

so you don't have to repeat the unlock operation.

## Loops

Don't squeeze everything on one line like this:

> ```
> ConnectionPool(size_t nWorkers, std::wstring baseUri) :BaseUri(baseUri)
> {
>     for (size_t i = 0; i < nWorkers; i++) Pool.emplace_back(http_client(baseUri), http_request(methods::GET));
> }
> ```

Directly using the constructor of `vector` looks better (and avoids reallocation):

```
ConnectionPool(std::size_t nWorkers, std::wstring_view baseUri)
    : BaseUri(baseUri)
    , Pool(nWorkers, {http_client(baseUri), http_request(methods::GET)})
{
}
```

This line is especially unreadable:

> ```
> for (size_t i = nDone = 0, limit = nActive = std::min(Pool.size(), WorkItems.size()); i < limit; ++i) assignWork(i, f);
> ```

Break it into lines:

```
nDone = 0;
limit = nActive = std::min(Pool.size(), WorkItems.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    assignWork(i, f);
}
```

## Miscellaneous

`size_t` → `std::size_t`.  And `#include <cstddef>` for it.

> ```
> #include <cpprest/http_client.h>
> #include<string>
> #include<vector>
> #include <mutex>
> #include <cpprest/filestream.h>
> ```

Two remarks:

- consistently put a space after `#include`;
- group `cpprest` headers together.